# Official Raspberry Pi 7" Display Backlight Control under Windows 10 IoT

Tags: raspberry-pi2, windows-10-iot-core

Is it possible to control the backlight for the Raspberry Pi 7" display under Windows 10 IoT Core? If so, does anyone know of any documentation or samples showing how?

I understand that support was added to the Linux display driver to enable this; I'm not certain if that same support was or is present in the Windows 10 IoT Core display driver, nor how to interface with it if it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Official Raspberry Pi 7" Display Backlight can be controlled by I2C registers.

```
string i2cDeviceSelector = I2cDevice.GetDeviceSelector();
IReadOnlyList<DeviceInformation> devices = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(i2cDeviceSelector);

var settings = new I2cConnectionSettings(0x45);
var screen = await I2cDevice.FromIdAsync(devices[0].Id, settings);

byte[] writeBuff = new byte[] { 0x86, 0x80 };
screen.Write(writeBuff);
```

More information is [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=105&t=152495).

And don't forget, that DSI connector does not support I2C. Using the jumper cables, connect SCL/SDA on the raspberry GPIO header to the horizontal pins marked SCL/SDA on the display board.